# Prerequisites for learning about lie algebras and their representations.

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, lie-algebras

What are the prerequisites for the topic 'Lie Algebras and their representations'? Actually, a course by this name is being offered at my university next semester and I want to know if I can take it. The official course description lists the following topics:

> Finite dimensional Lie algebras, Ideals, Homomorphisms, Solvable and Nilpotent Lie algebras, Semisimple Lie algebras, Jordan decomposition, Kiling form, root space decomposition, root systems, classification of complex semisimple Lie algebras Representations Complete reducibility, weight spaces, Weyl character formula, Kostant, steinberg and Freudenthal formulas

As of now, I am comfortable with measure theory and functional analysis but do not have a solid background in abstract algebra; I only know very basic things about groups like the notion of a homomorphism, etc. I am comfortable with basic point-set topology. I will be taking a course in complex analysis simultaneously with the course on lie algebras.

Comment: The prerequisites mainly are covered by abstract algebra. You can test yourself easily, by asking yourself whether you know about ideals, homomorphisms for rings, or solvable and nilpotent groups, for example. Also useful would be representation theory of finite groups.

Comment: Without commenting on the particular details here, I feel like I need to give some general advice for situations like this: Find out who is teaching the course and go talk to them.